# Problem sizing the icon from font awesome using react + tailwind + next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, size, font-awesome

I've been trying to learn react and tailwind and for some reason I can't size the icon from font awesome. I tried to do everything in  my power, using the `size="sm"` and `h-px w-px` from tailwind and nothing changes, please, can someone help me?

I am also using next.js

[How the icon looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWY3U.png)

[Link to the CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cocky-cori-dkk9c4?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.tsx%3A1%2C1)

./app/page.tsx

```
import Nav from "@/public/nav";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <div className="bg-red-700 w-full h-screen"></div>
    </>
  );
}
```

./app/global.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

./public/nav.tsx

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faUtensils } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function Nav() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span className="w-2 h-2">
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faUtensils}
          size="sm"
          style={{ color: "#00000d" }}
        />
      </span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to use `size="sm"` from fonts awesome and `h-px w-px` from tailwind and I looked for someone with the same problem here at the stack overflow and I found no solution.

Answer (score -1):

`size="sm"` should work.

[image: Edit serene-rui-qzm2cz]

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I did the same thing and got same issue, here is my link: 
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/cocky-cori-dkk9c4